# Typeorm how to find entities that does not have relation?

Tags: typeorm

Inside typeorm 0.3 we are able to find users who have posts by the next code:

```
userRepo.find({
   where: {
     posts: {
        post_id: Not(IsNull())
     }
   }, 
   relations: ['posts']
})
```

Does anyone know how to find users who have no posts at all (without using raw code)?